# Pintrest recipe rich pins cook time not showing

Tags: pinterest, microformats

I am having issues getting pintrest to pick up my dt-duration value on my web page.

I am using the h-recipe microformat method which pintrest support.

I've used the examples they provided on pintrest and microformat:
https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/recipes/
[http://microformats.org/wiki/h-recipe#Example](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/recipes/)

My current attempt:

```
<time class="dt-duration" datetime="15M">15 minutes</time>
```

All my other formats are getting picked up except for this. I feel I might be formatting this wrong but I cant find any where on my web search for acceptable format.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by changing the datetime value like so:

```
<time class="dt-duration" datetime="PT15M">15</time>
```